# Installing pycaw in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So I tried to pip install `pycaw` so I could use, from `pycaw.pycaw` import `AudioUtilities`, in my program but when I tried to pip install with pip install pycaw I get an error saying

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Carme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Carme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c302u53r\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Carme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c302u53r\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Carme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l9tmjphk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Carme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\comtypes' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the Visual Studio C++ build tools installed:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/